# Разбор предложения "Дело сопровождалось изрядной суматохой"

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, подлежащее

Где в этом предложении подлежащее и сказуемое:

**Дело  сопровождалось  изрядной  суматохой.**

(*Дело* - сущ.,  *сопровождалось изрядной суматохой* - составное сказ.?)

Comment: Марина, кажется, Вы путаете существительное с подлежащим.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4):

Подлежащее — дело, *(что делало?)* сопровождалось — сказуемое (страдательный залог); *(чем?)* суматохой — дополнение, *(какой?)* изрядной — определение.

Answer (score 1):

Дело сопровождалось изрядной суматохой.

**Предикативная основа: дело сопровождалось.** Сопровождалось – простое глагольное сказуемое, "сопровождаться суматохой" **не относится к устойчивым сочетаниям.**

СОПРОВОЖДАТЬСЯ, нсв. **чем.** 1. Происходить вместе, одновременно с чем-л.

СУМАТОХА, -и; ж. Беспорядочная беготня, суетливые хлопоты; суета, неразбериха.

Смысл предложения: Полезная деятельность происходила одновременно с суетой и беспорядочной беготней.